# Removing controller name from url does not work for more than one controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, routes

I want to remove controller name from url. It works for one controller but it does not work for more than one controller. Here is my code in Route.php:

```
 Router::connect('videos/:action', array('controller' => 'videos'));
 Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'frontends'));
```

but when I try to access `http://local.tbn24.dev/videos` it shows:

> Error: The action videos is not defined in controller FrontendsController

which proves the above url refer

```
Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'frontends'));
```

I want this url to reach the videos controller index function. How could I use both `Route::connect()` configuration?

Comment: how can I refer http://local.tbn24.dev/videos to 'controller' => 'videos' and 'action'=>'index'

Answer (score 1):

> but when I try to access `http://local.tbn24.dev/videos`

### There is no route for that

Of the two routes defined, this one does not match the above url as it is only one path segment:

```
Router::connect('videos/:action', array('controller' => 'videos'));
```

Therefore, it'll match the catch all route, with `videos` being interpretted as the action to look for.

*Also note that without a leading slash, the route won't match any request as they will **always** start with a leading slash*.

### A route to match only a controller name

To define a route to match `/videos` - either define a route to match that specific string:

```
Router::connect('/videos', array('controller' => 'videos', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Or, define a route with a restrictive pattern:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:controller', 
    array('action' => 'index'),
    array('controller' => 'videos|stuff'),
);
```

For more information on routes, check [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) for the version of CakePHP you are using.